# Leaflet conditionalLayer plugin map variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, leaflet

I'm moving a project to webpack, splitting code into modules, but at some places i bump into a situation where plugin or some other code expects *map* to be a visible global variable. The following exception are thrown because map is not exposed to it:

```
onRemove: function() {
  this._removeMarkers();
  this.onMap = false;
  map.off("moveend", this._update);
},

Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined
    at NewClass.onRemove (leaflet.conditionalLayer.js:77)
    at NewClass.removeLayer (Layer.js:185)
    at NewClass._onInputClick (Control.Layers.js:378)
    at HTMLInputElement.handler (DomEvent.js:79)
```

Currently i create the map variable in the bundle file (map.js in my case) which i load with the page, and import it in other modules like this

```
import { map } from './map.js';
```

All the leaflet code and leaflet plugins are imported as scripts without webpack. How can I share a *map* instance across all the scripts just like as it would be created without a module?

For now i worked around this problem and declared *map* as *window.map* in a module and it works, but it seems there is more convenient way of importing instead of using window object.

Comment: Is `leaflet.conditionalLayer.js` one of your plugins or app modules?

Comment: Yes, it's one of the plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in [leaflet-conditionalLayer](https://github.com/Eclipse1979/leaflet-conditionalLayer) plugin.

Its [`onRemove`](https://github.com/Eclipse1979/leaflet-conditionalLayer/blob/master/dist/leaflet.conditionalLayer.js#L74) method should either:

- Accept a `map` argument, as shown in [Leaflet tutorial for extending Controls](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html):

```js
    onRemove: function(map) {
        // (do something)
    }
```

- Or use `this._map` (instead of `map`) as suggested in (your?) issue https://github.com/Eclipse1979/leaflet-conditionalLayer/issues/6

The good news is that Leaflet class system should enable you to easily patch that plugin, without having to wait for the plugin author to fix this bug:

```js
L.ConditionalMarkers.include({
  onRemove: function (map) {
    this._removeMarkers();
    this.onMap = false;
    map.off("moveend", this._update);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah i posted an issue recently. But this is not the only plugin with the similar behavior that's why i'm in doubt if this variable should be accessible publicly. If not i just left it as a window variable, because it's a lot of places where global map variable is used.

Comment: Looks to me as a bug, possibly badly duplicated in several plugins. There is no reason to use such global variable.